# Plot recorded with recordPlot() not showing in Rnotebook

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am having trouble displaying plots inline on R notebook that I have created using the recorPlot() function. The chunks run without error but the recorded does not show. 
Below is a toy example.
The second chunk does not output the plot inline, as I would expect. But if I run the line on the console, the plot is displayed in the plot window. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

I am using:
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---


```{r, echo=FALSE}
plt_list = list()
for (i in 1:3){
    plot(c(i, i+1, i+2))
    plt_list[[i]] = recordPlot() 
}

```

```{r}
plt_list[[1]]
```
````